# Typescript: Object of T but value is Predicate

Tags: typescript

for the following function (see also http://ramdajs.com/docs/#where)

```
var spec2 = {x: function(val, obj) { return  val + obj.y > 10; }};
R.where(spec2, {x: 2, y: 7}); //=> false
R.where(spec2, {x: 3, y: 8}); //=> true
```

I would like to create the typing for the case where the `object` `T` has the value of a predicate.

I was thinking I would do something like this:

```
    where<T>(spec: {item: (val: any, testObj: T) => boolean}, testObj: T): boolean;
```

but I'm not sure what to do for the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a way to represent this in the TypeScript type system.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to get closer to a solution which is partially type safe:

```
interface Pred2<T> {
    (x: any, y: T): boolean
}
interface ObjPred2<T> {
    [index: string]: Pred2<T>;
}
where<T>(spec: ObjPred2<T>, testObj: T): boolean;
```